# Can't delete cloned git repo on my computer?

Tags: python, git, permissions, administrator

I uploaded my project folder to GitHub so I can work on it from both my desktop and my laptop.
I did some work on the project on my laptop and pushed the latest commit to GitHub and hopped on my desktop to see if it worked.

I accidentally cloned the repository to the wrong location, but when I went to delete it to clone it to the right folder, I got a pop-up saying that I "`need permission to perform this action. [I] require permission from <laptop user account> to make changes to this folder`".

I'm kind of stumped.
I tried taking control of the folder through Properties, but that hasn't seemed to change anything.

Comment: Could you show how how you tried deleting?

Comment: I just right-clicked and selected Delete from the context menu. I was able to delete the folder by deleting the files inside and working my way up, but I'm still curious if there's a way around that for future reference.

Comment: Check that no Git GUI software isn't using files from your repository

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS, but:

- a repository cloned into a wrong folder can simply be *moved* to the right folder (no need to re-clone)
- if that is not possible (no move or deletion), you can as a workaround leave it there, and re-clone it to the right directory

> I was able to delete the folder by deleting the files inside and working my way up

It is possible another process kept an handle on the folder itself, which would prevent its deletion.

Answer (score 0):

If you cloned it in the wrong directory, try moving it to the right directory.

If you finished working with it and wish to delete it, then:

Goto properties>security>edit permissions and give full control to your user account and then try deleting it, if that doesn't work, check if that directory is open in any other program(my directory was open in vscode), then try deleting it should work.